# Como converter para base64 em C#?

Tags: c#, base64

Eu estou utilizando o WebForms. Tem uma determinada parte dessa aplicação onde eu envio, através do Ajax, uma string base64, que se trata do código de uma imagem.

Eu estou acostumado a usar o PHP e utilizo as funções `base64_encode` e `base64_decode` para fazer as conversões para base64.

Mas em C# não faço a mínima ideia de como se faça isso.

Como decodificar um base64 em C# (e vice-versa)?

<sub>Não sei se é duplicada, não achei nada referente a isso no site</sub>

Comment: Você quer decodificar um Base64 em Imagem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o código se trata da manipulação de imagens então em C# não vai usar **`string`**, vai usar **`byte[]`** provavelmente, então o uso de:

- [**`System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)

E

- [**`System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzb9f993(v=vs.110).aspx)

Não fazem muito sentido, supondo que vá ler a imagem assim:

```
byte[] imagem = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"<caminho da imagem>");
```

Então basta passar a variável assim:

```
string imagebase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imagem);
```

Não tem por que usar string para isto.

Para decodificar deve usar `System.Convert.FromBase64String` que irá retornar em `byte[]` e depois pode salvar os valor disto em um arquivo, assim como desejar, exemplo:

```
string imagecodificadaembase64 = <valor em string do arquivo ou requisição em bas64>;
byte[] imagemdecodificada = System.Convert.FromBase64String(imagecodificadaembase64);
```

Answer (score 2):

Peguei [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743162/2405914)

Encode

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

Decode

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Comment: Supondo que esteja em UTF8 e for string esta ok ... se estiver em outro formato terá que ter cuidado com isto, não é uma solução que funciona magicamente, por exemplo, para não unicode provavelmente seria `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes`, para dados binários provavelmente já usaria os bytes diretamente (afinal, base64 geralmente é para fazer transporte de dados binários)